# Custom jar file was not loaded to Jmeter

Tags: java, maven, jmeter

I was testing to use Apache Jmeter to load test a java class. I set up a Maven project and added Jmeter dependencies. I was using v5.4.1 JMeter.

```
 <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And below is my simple java class for testing:

```
package jmeter.testing;

import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.AbstractJavaSamplerClient;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

public class ClassTester extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {
    @Override
    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
        SampleResult result = new SampleResult();
        result.sampleStart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("Testing Jmeter code...");
        }
        result.setResponseCode("200");
        result.setResponseMessage("Jmeter Test");
        result.setSampleLabel("test");
        result.sampleEnd();

        return result;
    }
}
```

I had Maven build this jar file and copied it to the /lib/ext directory. (My Jmeter was installed via brew..) And I didn't see this class in the Java Request Sampler somehow after I restarted JMeter. Could anyone guide me where was wrong? Thanks.

[INFO] Building jar: /Users/alex/Documents/IntelliJ/jmeter-util/target/jmeter-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

```
/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.4.1/libexec/lib/ext
❯ ls -ltr
-rw-r--r--@ 1 alex  staff     2726 Nov 11 17:16 jmeter-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code and your approach should be working, at least it does for me:

[image]

So check where your `jmeter` is pointing using [which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_(command)) and [ls -la](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls) commands, it might be the case you have some other JMeter in your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) which is different from `../Cellar/jmeter/5.4.1/bin/jmeter`

You can check out [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for more information on creating custom [Java Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler and other scripting approaches.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thank you for verifying it for me. I found the issue. I was using a different version of JDK (11) when I was building the jar. It worked after I re-built the jar using v17.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:
You will have to add your jar into the local repository and add the dependency to your pom.xml.

Reference : [How to add jar file to a maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

Can you copy the jar file to ${JMETER_HOME}/bin and check if it work?

`lib/ext` folder is for the Jmeter plugins. It's not for the utility jars. You can place the utility jars into the `lib` folder.

Your jar file need to be in the classpath.
Please see more details on the [classpath configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#classpath)

[More details](https://not-just-a-tester.blogspot.com/2013/12/configuring-jmeter-classpath.html)

Comment: I did uncommented user.classpath=../classes;../lib in the jemeter.properties file. I've tried to put the jar in lib/ext, lib, even /bin, none worked..

Comment: The solution will work when you start JMeter with jmeter.sh/jmeter.bat. Please check the other solution.